# Dropwizard deserializing generic list from JerseyClient

Tags: jersey, jackson, dropwizard

I wanted to implement a generic class to use for caching results from a REST API in a local MongoDB-instance. For this to work, I need to deserialize a collection I get from JerseyClient:

```
Response response = this.source.request().get();
List<T> list = response.readEntity( new GenericType<List<T>>() {} );

// ... do stuff with the list
```

Let's say I'm using this piece of code in a context of `T` relating to a class `Foo`. The really weird thing is, after the `readEntity` call, `list` is not a `List<Foo>`, instead is a `List<LinkedHashMap>`. How is that even possible, when I've clearly declared the Generic `T` to be `Foo`?

What do I have to do to get a proper `List<T>`, i.e. `List<Foo>` instead?

**Note:** If I remove the generic, and use

```
List<Foo> list = response.readEntity( new GenericType<List<Foo>>() {} );
```

directly instead, it works fine, but I really need that generic to be there!

Comment: The answer below works, but were you able to get this to work using something a little more simple?

Comment: For those struggling with this as I was, don't forget you can also simply read the entity as an array and then wrap it with a list afterwards: `readEntity(Foo[].class)`. I embarassingly spent hours debugging before thinking of this XD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java's most popular excuse for Generics: **Type Erasure**

If you can pass your class type as `Class<T> clazz`, then you can use this:

```
GenericType<List<T>> genericType = new GenericType<>(new ParameterizedType() {
  public Type[] getActualTypeArguments() {
    return new Type[]{clazz};
  }

  public Type getRawType() {
    return List.class;
  }

  public Type getOwnerType() {
    return null;
  }
});
response.readEntity(genericType);
```

Comment: `getOwnerType` should return `null` as written in the docs 
`Returns a {@code Type} object representing the type that this type is a member of.  For example, if this type is {@code O<T>.I<S>}, return a representation of {@code O<T>}.`

Comment: Thank you for the solution.

Comment: Still getting a `List<LinkedHashMap>` even using this, so incredibly frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
import sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl;
import javax.ws.rs.core.GenericType;

 GenericType<List<T>> genericType = new GenericType<>( 
        ParameterizedTypeImpl.make( List.class, new Type[]{classType}, null));
```