# Jackson client read generic List<T> method does not work

Tags: java, jax-rs

I have a jax-rs 2.0 client that tries to read a generic list of type t. Instead of creating a list of type t is creates a list of type LinkedHashMap

```
public static <T> List<T> getList(Builder reqeustBuilder, Class<T> t) {

        Response response = reqeustBuilder.get();
        List<T> responseEntityList =  response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<T>>(){});
        return responseEntityList;

}
```

I found a workaround here: [Jackson generic json to List<T> converter method does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29242530/jackson-generic-json-to-listt-converter-method-does-not-work) but I would like to figure out why the above code does not work and if there is a way to fix it.

**Update:** 
I found another solution here: [Dropwizard deserializing generic list from JerseyClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307302/dropwizard-deserializing-generic-list-from-jerseyclient)

I'm wondering if there is something a little more simple. I don't understand why T==Object in this case and not the type passed.

Comment: _"I don't understand why T==Object "_. Google "what is type erasure". I am voting to close this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you have a typo.

```
public static <T> List<T> getList(Builder reqeustBuilder, Class<T> t) {
```

Should be

```
public static List<T> getList(Builder reqeustBuilder, Class<T> t) {
```

Secondly, the reason it is returning a type `LinkedHashMap` is because that is the type of data structure returned by your function `readEntity` in the following line:

```
List<T> responseEntityList =  response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<T>>(){});
```

Comment: Is there a way to make response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<T>>(){}); retrun a list of type t instead of the LinkedHash map? I am not passing LinkedHashMap as the t parameter.

Comment: Also, public static List<T> getList(Builder reqeustBuilder, Class<T> t) does not compile.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. What is the answer to this question?